# ¿Como hacer lineas continuas y no poligonales al dibujar rutas con osmdroid?

Tags: java, android, geojson

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de rutas con openStreetMap en android, usando osmdroid, la cuestión es que no encuentro en que parte de mi código le estoy diciendo que haga las lineas de la manera en que sale en la primer fotografía (Linea purpura), anteriormente me salia como en la segunda fotografía(Linea negra) y así es como lo necesito.

No quiero cambiar el color, sino que no se corten las lineas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi metodo asigno a mi variable String miGeoJson un geojson que obtengo y ya cargo el mapa.

```
private void myOSM(){

        try {
            GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(28.711524, -106.105379);

            MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
            map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
            map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
            map.getController().setZoom(15);
            map.setMaxZoomLevel(null);
            map.canZoomIn();
            map.canZoomOut();
            map.setUseDataConnection(true);
            map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            map.setClickable(true);
            map.getController().animateTo(myGeoPoint);

            MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(map);
            map.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
            myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
            myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();

            KmlDocument kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
            kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(miGeoJson);/// miGeoJson es mi String convertido ya en json

            Drawable defaultMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
            Bitmap defaultBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) defaultMarker).getBitmap();
            Style defaultStyle = new Style(defaultBitmap, 0x886103a0, 25f, 0x886103a0);
            FolderOverlay geoJsonOverlay = (FolderOverlay) kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(map, defaultStyle, null, kmlDocument);


            map.getOverlays().add(geoJsonOverlay);
            map.invalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```